# Logical operation in R - different results

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'dd' of 753 x 3 and all variables are of numeric class.

```
str(dd)
'data.frame':   753 obs. of  3 variables:
$ A: num  1.9 2 1.1 0.636 0.9 ...
$ B: num  1.1 0.222 0.6 0.364 0.8 ...
$ C: num  0 -0.8 -0.2 0 -0.2 -0.5 0.1 0 -0.9 0.1 ...
```

I did the histogram of the first variable and store it in a variable.

```
h1 <- hist(dd[, 1], breaks = 25, plot = F)
str(h1)
List of 6
$ breaks  : num [1:24] -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 ...
$ counts  : int [1:23] 5 3 5 9 20 25 36 43 45 51 ...
$ density : num [1:23] 0.0664 0.0398 0.0664 0.1195 0.2656 ...
$ mids    : num [1:23] -0.25 -0.15 -0.05 0.05 0.15 0.25 0.35 0.45 0.55 0.65  ...
$ xname   : chr "dd[, 1]"
$ equidist: logi TRUE
- attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Then I identify the first and last index where density > 0.3 and store the corresponding breaks into a variable.

```
index <- which(h1$density > 0.3)
ll <- as.numeric(h1$breaks[index[1]])
ul <- as.numeric(h1$breaks[index[length(index)]])
```

The values of ll is 0.2 and ul is 1.6. When I tried to find number of observations that has greater than ul for the first variable, I get 105:

```
sum(dd[, 1] > ul)
[1] 105
```

But, if I do

```
sum(dd[, 1] > 1.6)
[1] 72
```

I am stuggling to understand these results (may be a trivial one but I am lost). Could someone please help me to understand the differences?

Comment: I can't replicate this using my own dummy data. Since we can't actually see the value of `ul` my guess would be that is not `1.6`. You can check this with: `all.equal(ul, 1.6)`

Comment: `all.equal(ul, 1.6)`
`[1] TRUE`

Comment: Can you post a `dput(hist) `?